# C++ - Open Control Panel item in the same window

Tags: c++, windows, shell-extensions

I have a Windows-based application. I'm trying to open a Control Panel item the following way:

```
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProcMy, ppid);
IOpenControlPanel *pPanel = NULL;
CoInitialize(nullptr);
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_OpenControlPanel, NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IOpenControlPanel,
    (void**)&pPanel);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    return -1;
}
pPanel->Open(CUSTOM_GUID, NULL, NULL);
```

This however opens the Control Panel Item in a new Window. Is there any way to navigate to the Control Panel item in an already Open Window? I have the Handle to the Window.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a running instance of control panel you can do somewhat like.

> *Retrieves a pointer to a running object that has been registered.*

Sample code

```
IUnknown *puk = NULL;         
HRESULT hr = GetActiveObject(CLSID_OpenControlPanel, 0, &puk);
return (hr == S_OK);
```